# Changing out a light switch for a smart light switch

Tags: smart-switch

I have a light switch in my garage that controls my outside garage lights. A same switch by my front door controls those lights.  I would like to replace one of these switches with a smart switch.  My existing switch has 3 black wires, 1 red wire, and a ground wire.  My new switch is:  red, white, black, and neutral.  Can I replace my existing switch with my new smart switch?

Comment: Any whites in back of the box and not connected to the switch?  Neutrals are white, but white is not always neutral.  Smart switches(most of them) require neutral to work.

Comment: @crip659 said most of it. In addition, "new switch is red white black and neutral" is patently false. (Unless it is total foreign junk). Most likely it is "red white black and green" - where green is ground, not neutral and white is neutral.

Comment: You need a 3way smart switch, ( if there is such a thing.)

Comment: There are whites, but not connected to the switch.  There is one black that is stuck right into the mid-back portion of the switch.  Cannot find what that does.  I am sure it has a purpose, just don’t know what that is.  My house is only 5 years old.

Comment: "Whites but not connected to the switch" is 100% **normal** for a non-smart switch. Sometimes a non-smart 3-way switch will have a white connected, but since yours has 3 blacks and a red, that indicates either neutral is passed on the white wire (which is good, actually) or you have conduit and colors can get even more confusing. **Please upload pictures showing the switch boxes and all the wires attached to each switch - both garage and front door.**

Comment: Are you planning on replacing _one_ of the 3-way switches with a smart switch or both? Some smart 3-ways can work with a dumb switch in the other position, others need a companion "slave" switch in the other position, others need _two_ smart switches, the last two conditions mean they both need to be changed. Including the brand/model of your planned new switch would be helpful.